# How to kill a child process once it hangs so it doesn't block the parent(BASH)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

stop_service {
  $(service $1 stop)
}

servicename=$(inictl list | grep $1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
servicestate=$(initctl list | grep "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f2)
servicepid=$(initctl list | grep  "$1" | cut -d "," -f2 | cut -d " " -f3)
stop_service $servicename &

if [ \( $servicestate = "stop/killed," \) -o \( $servicestate = "start/killed," \) ] ;then
   /upstartCleaner/upstartCleaner $servicepid
   echo "Command executed"
else
  echo "The service didnt crash"
fi
```

What I want to do is run the stop_service as a child process and then on the parent process be able to tell if the child process hanged and kill it, or be able to detach its execution from the parent process so it doesn't hang when it stops.

Every time I run this script and the child process stops responding or hangs this in turn stops the execution of every line of the parent process after the stop_service $servicename & line.

Comment: It seems you need some kind of watchdog functionality. Let your child process log to some file or update it's state every few seconds, and from other process just check if update is not too old. If so, then restart your child process.

Comment: Once you apply the `&` after stop_service, it forks a child. This child creates a snapshot of the variables in the script's scope - but updating these variables does not change the parent variables. Only alters the child process snapshot. Look into SHM - and 'send an event' to the parent

Answer (score 0):

i suppose  the easy way is better, just output the id of the child process
and add it to kill, so something like this.

```
id=$process_id
kill $id
```

Comment: I could edit your answer, looks like this word filter is only for low-rep users. On another note, are you sure the reverse quotes are needed here?

Comment: yeah, my mistake, it should be dollar_sign, changed that.... :)  works fine like that... checked!

Comment: The problem is that once the child process crashes the parent process halts as well and I am unable to kill it .

Comment: hmmm i would understand the opposite and that would make sense, but this makes no sense, cant you use nohup (no hang up) or something similar to that in order to differenciate the relationship between them and so they wouldnt see what the other is doing. so that could solve your problem.

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida i was just going through some of my old answers, and i remembered of this, i dont know if you finally solved this, but just for the record if you didnt, check out the zombie processes because i think this is whats happening here and could be of help to you. Using the `kill -s SIGCHLD <ppid>` will tell to the parent to kill his child process adn throught his the parent will not crash because he is doing that "legal" action. check out this reference, http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/17776

Answer (score 0):

The parent process runs its course until the last line in your script.However it has to wait for any child processes it has spawned, in order for it to release its execution/process.

Depending on your usecase, what you could do, is loop for a while in the parent, and see if child finishes.

In your script, fork your child process with `&`

```
stop_service $servicename &
```

Then immediately after, pick up the process id (PID) via `$!`

```
proc_id=$!
```

The following will loop for a couple of seconds and see if child has completed - otherwise abruptly kill the child - and attempt to kill the service.

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do
   if [ -d /proc/$proc_id ]; then
      # child is alive
      sleep 1s
   else
       break
   fi
done
if [ -d /proc/$proc_id ]; then
   # child did not complete within time
   kill $proc_id
   ps -ef | grep your_process_name | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
fi
```